# Trying to get small program running in terminal, receiving error

Tags: ruby, terminal, rubygems, undefined

At this point, I am just trying to display some basic lines from a file with my command line.

Heres my module:

```rb
require "reverb_exercise/version"

module ReverbExercise
  class Parser
    attr_accessor :records

    def parse_file(file)
      @lines = []
      File.open(file, "r") do |file|
        file.each_line do |line|
          @lines << line
        end
      end
      @lines
    end

    def build_records
      @records = []
      @lines.each do |line|
        @records << Record.new(*line.split(", "))
      end
      @records
    end
  end

  class Record
    attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name, :gender, :color, :birthdate

    def initialize(first_name, last_name, gender, color, birthdate)
      @first_name = first_name
      @last_name = last_name
      @gender = gender
      @color = color
      @birthdate = birthdate
    end
  end
end
```

And here's  the bin folder:

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'reverb_exercise'

puts ReverbExercise::Parser.new.parse_file("comma.txt")
```

When I run `reverb` in my terminal, I receive the following `undefined local variable or method` error:

> Users/yedidyaweiner/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/reverb_exercise-0.0.1/lib/reverb_exercise.rb:10:in `block (2 levels) in parse_file': undefined local variable or method`lines' for # (NameError)

What am I missing?

Comment: your code doesn't produce errors for me

Comment: Did you do a save in your editor before going to the command-line?

Comment: Thanks guys. I had neglected to run `rake install`